# Emacs C++ mode Constructor initialize incorrect indent

Tags: emacs, emacs24

My emacs default indent like this:

```
FileChannel::FileChannel(const std::string &file_path) :
file_path_(file_path), fd_(0)
{  
}
```

but I want it like that:

```
FileChannel::FileChannel(const std::string &file_path) :
    file_path_(file_path), fd_(0)
{  
}
```

or:

```
FileChannel::FileChannel(const std::string &file_path)
    : file_path_(file_path), fd_(0)
{  
}
```

How should I change my config?

Comment: I think you can get the latter one with `google-c-style` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your .emacs:

```
(defun my-c-c++-mode-init ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'member-init-intro '+))

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'my-c-c++-mode-init)
```